# Is it possible to create a trigger for inserting data of a table on another table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm learning about Oracle and I have a query, if like says in the title, create a trigger that can insert data from one table into another table. How can I do it? if I have this tables:

```
create table personal(
    id_person);

create table mine(
    id_mine,
    name_mine,
    pay);

create table trip(
    id_trip,
    id_person,
    name_mine,
    date_trip);

create table assignment(
    id_assig,
    id_trip,
    pay);
```

The column ***pay*** in the table ***assignment*** is the column that I want to insert automatically from the table ***mine*** through the trigger.

Comment: What event triggers the population of `assignment`? INSERT on `trip`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you may use a (*BEFORE* or *AFTER*) *INSERT* trigger defined on the table *MINE* as the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_ins_mine
BEFORE INSERT ON mine
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  v_assigID assignment.id_assig%type := seq_assig.nextval;
  v_tripID  assignment.id_trip%type  := seq_trip.nextval;
BEGIN         
    insert into assignment( id_assig, id_trip, pay)
    values( v_assigID, v_tripID, :new.pay);
 -- this pay in (:new.pay) comes from inserted column value of the table "mine"
END;
```

Comment: What's the advantage of the BEFORE trigger over an AFTER trigger here?

Comment: @DavidFaber In this case, there will be no difference. As a habit I prefer `before`, and for dml statement in a row-level `after` type trigger, we might meet `mutating trigger problem` more probably than triggers with `before`... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the primary keys on your tables are `IDENTITY` columns.

In order to insert the value of `pay` from the table `mine` into the table `assignment`, you need to know the value of `id_trip`. This can be gotten from the value of `name_mine` but I have to wonder if this value is unique? Will it return a single value of `id_trip` or can it return multiple values? Is `date_trip` involved somehow? These are all questions to which you'll need to know the answer in order to write this trigger properly. Nevertheless, here goes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_mine_pay
 AFTER INSERT ON mine
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO assigment
    ( id_trip, pay )
  SELECT id_trip, :new.pay
    FROM trip
   WHERE mine_name = :new.mine_name;
END;
/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: exactly, the column name_mine it's a unique value for this reason I set y the table trip, thank you for your help I'm starting to edit my trigger